# how to fix "MySQL 1064 error Syntax Workbench"

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql and I have this problem with my code

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnejEdad_Obtener
(

p_fechaNacimiento date,

p_fechaHoy date
)

RETURNS int

BEGIN

    declare v_edad int;

set v_edad = TIMESTAMPDIFF (year,p_fechaNacimiento, p_fechaHoy);

if (DATEPART(month, p_fechaNacimiento) > DATEPART(month,p_fechaHoy))
    then

set v_edad = v_edad - 1;

else if
(DATEPART
(month, p_fechaNacimiento) <= DATEPART
(month,p_fechaHoy)) and
(DATEPART
(DAY, p_fechaNacimiento) > DATEPART
(DAY,p_fechaHoy))
    then
set v_edad = v_edad - 1;

end
if;

    IF v_edad < 0 THEN
SET v_edad = 0;
END
IF; -- > update 

    RETURN v_edad;

END;
```

Comment: I edited your code so that workbench would show an error . What exactly didin't work?

Comment: What is the complete error message?

Comment: @nbk Did you edit the code so WB would show an error, or so it would NOT show an error? Your comment is the opposite of what you added to the question.

Comment: I@Barmar it show **no errors anymore**. it is only a typo.

Comment: @nbk If the question is about a syntax problem, you shouldn't fix the problem in your edits. If it's just a typo, explain it in a comment and vote to close.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the help

Comment: @nbk What is the typo?

Comment: else if is wrong, it has to be written elseif

Comment: @nbk I have problems with other functions, it makes the same mistake, could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function has to be as follows.
Elseif has be to be written together.

```
DELIMITER //
    CREATE FUNCTION fnejEdad_Obtener
    (p_fechaNacimiento date,p_fechaHoy date)

    RETURNS int

    BEGIN

        declare v_edad int;

        set v_edad = TIMESTAMPDIFF(year,p_fechaNacimiento, p_fechaHoy);

        if (DATEPART(month, p_fechaNacimiento) > DATEPART(month,p_fechaHoy)) then    
          set v_edad = v_edad - 1;      
        elseif
          (DATEPART(month, p_fechaNacimiento) <= DATEPART(month,p_fechaHoy)) and
          (DATEPART(DAY, p_fechaNacimiento) > DATEPART(DAY,p_fechaHoy)) then
         set v_edad = v_edad - 1;

        end if;

        IF v_edad < 0 THEN
        SET v_edad = 0;
        END IF; -- > update 

        RETURN v_edad;

    END

//

DELIMITER ;
```